# Create bookmark with a query string on browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, bookmarks

I want to create "Bookmark Me" link button on my web site. I am using below javascript code to create the bookmark on browser.

I want to pass some query-string (arg) to the URL. But this doesn't work properly with most of browsers. Is there any better way to do this?

```
    function CreateBookmark(arg) {
        try {
            var title = "MyWebSite";
            var url = "http://www.MyWebSite.com/" + arg;
            if (window.sidebar) { //mozilla
                window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, '');
            }
            else if (window.external && window.external.AddFavorite!=null && document.all) {
                window.external.AddFavorite(url, title);
            }
            else {
                // But, this doesn't take the url with query string
                alert('Press ctrl+d to bookmark after you click OK');
            }

        }
        catch (ex) { alert(ex); }
    }
```

Comment: Wow; I thought those links had died their worthy death by now! why are you trying to duplicate functionality that **already exists** in the browser? but: can you clarify: when you say "doesn't work properly with most of browsers" - what happens? or what doesn't happen? I also have images of the iOS/android/etc users turning their device over looking for a ctrl key

Comment: @MarcGravell: I am getting an error saying, ".. No method AddFavorite"

Comment: @MarcGravell: I want to create a bookmark with generated query string which contains encrypted username and password to login.

Comment: why not just link to it and have the user bookmark if from there? (and note: a bookmark link is a GET, so should be idempotent - it shouldn't be logging them in, really)

Comment: (the short answer here is: many browsers either *have never* offered this, or *no longer* offer this)

Comment: "why not just link to it and have the user bookmark if from there" - Sorry I didn't get you properly. Did you mean give the url to user and let him to create the bookmark manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to implement this because of security restrictions.